# Set Asp.Net Chart tick marks to start at axis min value and end and max value

Tags: asp.net, charts, label

I'm using the Asp.net built in chart control to render a gantt chart and it looks like this [image]
<sub>(source: [easycaptures.com](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/426/2525794537.png))</sub>
.

How do I get the axis labels to start from the axis min value (20.1.2012) and the last label to be at the max value (20.2.2012).

Regards,
Mathias

Answer (score 0):

ChartArea.AxisY.Maximum = MAX_VAL;
ChartArea.AxisY.Minimum = MIN_VAL;

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I already have  chartGantt.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = projectStarts.ToOADate();  chartGantt.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = projectEnds.ToOADate();  and it still does that.